# GridView: how to provide equal height to each row programmatically?

Tags: android, layout, gridview

Can anyone help me to make each row's height same in `GridView` programmatically?

I want to provide equal weight to each row of `GridView`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: atleast provide some code what did you tried and then ask for where do get stuck ?

Answer (score 0):

For that you ca do as following.

Use grid view with custom adapter and in custom adapter you can use cell layout

for eg. **CELL:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llGridItem"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#def" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGridItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white_smoke" />

</LinearLayout>
```

for custom grid you can reffer this [link](http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.in/2013/09/android-custom-gridview-example.html) and [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/android-custom-grid-view-example-with-image-and-text.html) .